# Android: How to initialise a custom View in code and connect it to an existing xml view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-resources

I have my own custom view class like below:

```
public class speak extends ConstraintLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

    
    private TextView text;
    private ImageView img;

    public speak(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.speak,
                0, 0);
        try {
            
            text = findViewById(a.getResourceId(R.styleable.speak_text,0));
            img = findViewById(a.getResourceId(R.styleable.speak_img, 0));

        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

    }
}
```

With this I created `attr.xml` where I put this resource:

```
<declare-styleable name="speak">      
    <attr name="text" format="string"/>
    <attr name="img" format="reference"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

and I also created my own layout xml of how the custom view should look. This way I can add  multiple views easily in `activity_main.xml`. I started by adding one view in `activity_main.xml`. But now I want to link it to the custom view class in `onCreate`. what I am doing is this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    speak sl =  findViewById(R.id.ss);
    sl.seImage(getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.app:drawable/img.png", null, null));
}
```

where `setImage` is my own setter for the components in the customView. However, this is returning a `null pointer exception` which I think I understand since I am not creating a new `speak` Object and passing attributes in the constructor and so on.

create a new view object but at the same time pass it the xml element which sets its position on screen apart form other stuff.

I am also not sure what should I pass to `AttributeSet` in the constructor.

## udpate

this is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
```

This is because my setter contains img.SetImageResource(int) to get a drawable Id and set te image to that image in drawable folder

Answer (score 0):

Please check GoEditText I have used:

```
 public class GoEditText extends FrameLayout {
     private TextInputLayout inputLayout;
     private AppCompatEditText editText;

     public GoEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
      }

       public GoEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);
          init(context, attrs);
       }

        private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           this.context = context;
           LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.go_edit_text, this, true);
           inputLayout = findViewById(R.id.inputLayout);
           editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
           if (attrs != null) {
             TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, 
                R.styleable.GoEditText, -1, 0);
             int edtType = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.GoEditText_edtTextType, 0);
             boolean isEditable = typedArray.getBoolean( 
               R.styleable.GoEditText_isEditAble, true);
           }

}
```

Below is xml go_edit_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@null">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        style="@style/CJEditText"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/gray_3" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Now you can use it directly in acitivity.xml as

```
<com.package.name.component.GoEditText
        android:id="@+id/myid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:edtTextType="selection"
        app:errorMsg="@string/error_employee_type"
        app:hint="@string/hint_employee_type" />
```

Now in onCreate

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
     GoEditText edt= findViewById(R.id.myId);
     edt.editText.setText("hello");
}
```

Or you can create a getter method in CustomView for say edittext( imageView in your case)

Comment: So by having a constructor that does not have AttributeSet one can call it in on create?

Comment: this still does not explain how to call it in on create. What you posted is almost exactly like what I already have.

Comment: You can use your defined Custom View in your xml. Can you add activity_main.xml to the question?

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out and review it. Do you use an attr.xml for <declare-stylable>

Comment: @SanjayKumar this is still giving me a null pointer exception because you are not calling the constructor in onCreate() which initialises the  elements

Comment: @user7331538 Please post trace of exception. So that i can suggest you a solution.

Comment: what is this :  img = findViewById(a.getResourceId(R.styleable.speak_img, 0)); you can't find view like that. Right way is  "findViewById(R.id.yourImg);" AND have inflated a view in Your CustomView like that "   LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.go_edit_text, this, true);"